# SQL Server Job alert

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sp-send-dbmail

How can I set up a job alert in SQL Server to an email when any agent SQL Server jobs in a server stops running after 30 mins threshold?

I tried with this script:

```
DECLARE @profile_name VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Default Profile; 
DECLARE @email_to_address VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Domain@myemail.com'; 
DECLARE @email_subject VARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @email_body VARCHAR(MAX);

WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = @profile_name,`your text`
      @recipients = @email_to_address,
      @subject = @email_subject, `your text`
      @body_format = 'html',
      @body = @email_body;

SELECT @email_subject = 'Missed Job Alert: ' + ISNULL (@@SERVERNAME, CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS VARCHAR(MAX))); 

SELECT @email_body = 'At least one job run was missed on ' +  ISNULL(@@SERVERNAME, CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS VARCHAR(MAX))) +  during the period ' + CAST(@start_time_local AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 

END
```

Comment: Jobs *don't* stop after 30 minutes though. If your job is stopping after 30 minutes *something* is causing it to, so you can just have that *thing* handle the email, no?

Comment: least job on the server is scheduled to run every 30 mins and I want to get an email alert after 30mins if that job or any other agent job failed

Comment: What if the job that checks for stopped jobs get stuck over 30 minutes

Comment: But the job hasn't failed; it's still running. If you want an email on *faliure* then use the notifications feature to send a notification to an Operator. [Notify an Operator of Job Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/notify-an-operator-of-job-status?view=sql-server-ver16)